# I am trying to get data from https://www.metaweather.com/api/ through fetch method,and it's not getting me

Tags: fetch

fetch ('https://crossorigin.me/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/2487956/')

```
.then(result => {
    console.log(result);
})
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

asynchronous.html:200 GET https://crossorigin.me/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/2487956/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
(anonymous) @ asynchronous.html:200
asynchronous.html:205 TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Have you actually tried to access that URL? I think you'll find its invalid. Surely the URL just needs to be https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/2487956/?

Comment: sure i did it,but the proxy is no more existing.I used another site